# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date exception at date UTC conversion

Tags: datetime, simpledateformat, utc, unparseable

I am trying to convert my date in UTC format, for that I have to parse it using SimpleDateFormat class. But it is giving me Unparseable date exception. My code is given below:

```
//My date coming from server:  Wed Dec 23 13:00:00 GMT+04:00 2015

SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM EE- HH:mm:ss yy");
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date myDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(s1.datefrom + "");
```

Comment: s1 is my object from which i am getting my date.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work :`SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy",Locale.US);`

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: upper case "Z" shouldn't work for OP example. "Z" is the full numeric offset, +0400, OP is looking for "GMT+04:00", which would be lower case "z" according to the docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#timezone

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Apparently you want to parse a string that represents a moment with a wall-clock time four hours ahead of UTC, and then adjust into UTC wall-clock time.

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( 
    "Wed Dec 23 13:00:00 GMT+04:00 2015" ,
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss OOOO uuuu" , Locale.US )
)
.toInstant()           // Adjust from four hours ahead of UTC to UTC itself by extracting a `Instant`. 
.toString()
```

> 2015-12-23T09:00:00Z

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes rather than the terrible old *java.time* classes.

```
String input = "Wed Dec 23 13:00:00 GMT+04:00 2015" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss OOOO uuuu" , Locale.US ) ;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

> odt.toString(): 2015-12-23T13:00+04:00

If you want to adjust that into UTC, the simplest approach is to extract an `Instant`. The `Instant` class is always in UTC, by definition.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant() ;
```

Or, to retain the flexibility of `OffsetDateTime`, call `withOffsetSameInstant`. Pass the constant [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC).

```
OffsetDateTime odtUtc = odt.withOffsetSameInstant( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

If you must use the awful legacy class `java.util.Date`, convert from `Instant`.

```
java.util.Date d = java.util.Date.from( instant ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).